# Code tracing and logical errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class MyHashTable:

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.slots = [None] * self.capacity

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.slots )

    def __len__(self):
        count = 0
        for i in self.slots:
            if i != None:
                count += 1
        return count

    def hash_function(self, key):
        slot = key % len(self.slots)

        if key in self.slots:
            return slot

        elif (not key in self.slots) and len(self.slots) == self.capacity:
            return slot

        else:
            for i in self.slots:
                count = 0 
                if i == None:
                    return count
                count += 1

    def insert(self, key):
        print(len(self.slots)) #Why does this show an output of 2? 
        if key in self.slots:
            return -2

        elif (not key in self.slots) and (len(self.slots) != self.capacity): #Now this cant execute
            num = hash_function(key)
            self.slots[num] = key
            return num

        elif (not key in self.slots) and len(self.slots) == self.capacity:
            return -1
```

Im wondering why the commented part above in the `insert(self, key)` the print statement gives (2) instead of (0). The elif statement underneath wont execute since its giving a result of (2) instead of (0)

A function call of

```
x = MyHashTable(2)
print(len(x))
```

Should give: 0

Comment: You should not compare to `None` with `==`.  Instead you should test as e.g. `if i is None`, or `if i is not None`

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing `self.slots = [None] * self.capacity`, so with `capacity = 2`, `self.slots` is `[None, None]`, which is of length 2.

Your `__len__` method doesn't run because `len(self.slot)` calls `self.slot.__len__`, not `self.__len__`. If you'd like to use your override method, you should be calling `len(self)` instead.

Comment: But what about 
    def __len__(self):
      
Shouldnt this override the len() function and thus give 2?

Comment: that override is for the class/object itself, not `self.slot` . doing `len(self.slot)` , would call that list's `__len__()` . I am guessing you wanted to do `len(self)` .

Comment: @WojackO'feel As Anand noted, the `__len__` override is for your `MyHashTable` class, not for `self.slot` (which is an instance of `list`).

Answer (score 1):

You have to call your __len__ function (by calling `self.__len__()` ) if you want the length of the elements which are not None. For lists None are valid entries.

By the way. It is always best to compare with None by `a is None` or `a is not None` instead of `==` or `!=`.

Comment: How exactly do I call the __len__ function? I thought len() would be overrided, by the way why is "a is None" better than the == operator?

Comment: simply use `self.__len__()` or `len(self)` instead of `len(self.slots)`

Comment: Ah, you have overwritten the len-function but only for your class and not for the array you use for `self.slots`. That one is always referring to `self.slots.__len__` and not to `self.__len__`. About the difference between `==` and `is`: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ (see the second point in the section about `Programming Recommendations`)